# How to fix 'duplicate symbol' from importing h file in glm

Tags: c++, linker, glm-math

I'm currently working on a graphics project, and have come across an issue. I have two separate cpp files that both require the glm gtx extensions. The problem is, when both files #include "glm/ext.hpp", I get the following error: "duplicate symbol glm::floor_log2(unsigned int)".

I understand what the error means, and what is causing it (each compilation unit having its own version of the "glm::floor_log2(unsigned int)" function), but I don't understand how to get around it. Both files require access to the ext header, and will not compile without it (though together, they will not link).

How do I go about properly getting my project to compile and link?

Comment: Use the `extern` keyword in the `.h` file.

Comment: Put them in different namespaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `floor_log2` is declared in `integer.hpp` (without `inline` keyword), and defined in `integer.inl` (included from `integer.hpp`).

It is a bug in the `glm` source.

You should add `inline` to the declaration in `integer.hpp` (which will fix your problem) and notify developers of `glm` that they have a bug.